# Low brightness in a Intel Mobile GM956/GL960

Tags: power-management, intel-graphics

I'm installing Debian stable (7.0) on a old Dell Vostro 1500 and I noticed that the brightness is always low. I've searched around and the only thing I've found is adding `nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor` to the kernel init commands, that only mess up with the graphic card and reduces the maximum resolution. How can I really showoff the real brightness of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently the recommendations I've found were not totally wrong. I removed the `nomodeset` part and everything was fine and dandy. I didn't find out why in none of the logs. Here is the relevant part of the `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_backlight=vendor"
```